# Alguna alternativa para cuando no tengo un tamaño en concreto sobre un arreglo?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

El arreglo es para acomodar la conversión de decimal a binario/octal/hexadecimal, ya que puede variar la cantidad de elementos dentro del arreglo, ¿Cómo podría dejar el tamaño del arreglo sea determinado por la cantidad números pueda ser dividido por 2/8/16, etc?

Gracias por la atención.

```
void hexadecimal(int h){
    
    //Variable para decimal a hexa
    int hexa, divexa, mulexa, resexa;
    
    int acom[];
    int i = 0;
    
        //ciclo para repetir el proceso hasta llegar a 0
        do
        {
            
            //pasos para convertir a hexa
            divexa=hexa/16;
            mulexa=divexa*16;
            acom[i]=abs(mulexa-hexa);
            
            //cuando la resta de un numero mayor a 9
            if(acom[i]>9 && acom[i]<16)
            {
                
                if (acom[i]==10) cout<< hexa << divexa << "| A | \n";
                
                if (acom[i]==11) cout<< hexa << divexa << "| B | \n";
                
                if (acom[i]==12) cout<< hexa << divexa << "| C | \n";
                
                if (acom[i]==13) cout<< hexa << divexa << "| D | \n";
                
                if (acom[i]==14) cout<< hexa << divexa << "| E | \n";
                
                if (acom[i]==15) cout<< hexa << divexa << "| F | \n";
                
            } else cout<< hexa << divexa << resexa;
            
            hexa=divexa;
            
            i++;
            
        }while(hexa<<=0);
    
        for(int j = i; j>=0; j--){
            
            cout<< "El hexadecimal es: ";
            cout<< acom[j];
                    
        }
    
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: creo que no estas usando la variable h

Comment: @GregorioVaronRengifo de hecho no, y justo eso pensé cuando estaba formulando la pregunta, la h seria la variable hexa en este caso

Comment: El error en concreto es porque el array lo has de declarar con un numero determinado de indices, es decir, con un tamaño concreto. Esto lo puedes hacer de forma explícita:  `int acom[3]` (por ejemplo) o implícita `int acom[]={1,2,3}` Por otro lado mirando el código de reojo me llama la atención que no uses el parámetro `h` de la función y que trabajes con variables sin inicializar, por lo que me da que esa función tiene fallos.

Answer (score 0):

**Opción 1: Memoria dinámica**

Puedes usar la memoria dinámica directamente. Creas un arreglo con `new[]` del tamaño que necesites.

```
int numElementos = 500;
int * acom = new int[numElementos];

// ...

delete[] acom;
```

**Opción 2: Contenedores**

También puedes hacer uso de los contenedores de la STL. Estos contenedores usarán memoria dinámica por detrás, pero tu te puedes despreocupar de su gestión.

```
std::vector<int> acom;

for( int i=0; i<numElementos; i++)
    acom.push_back(numero);
```